# way to purge all but one object types (models) in a realm

Tags: swift, realm

I want to `realm.delete()` all but one model in my realm. Is there any way to do this without listing all of them?
Maybe a way to loop through all the types currently existing in a realm?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can access the types from your Realm configuration, filter them to exclude the one you want to keep than delete each object of each type that you don't want to keep.

```
let typeToBeKept = MyObjectClass.self
realm.configuration.objectTypes?.filter{$0 != typeToBeKept}.forEach{ type in
    try! realm.write {
        realm.delete(realm.objects(type.self))
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi David I used your solution but I got every time this error : Could not cast value of type 'Element' (0x1012cf2e8) to 'RealmSwift.Object' (0x102e00bc0) which I Didn't understand

Comment: @WalidSassi please include the actual code that you are using that produces said exception.

Comment: the problem is that Element is a objc realm model so the compiler tell me that they can't delete objc realm model which I think didn't make sens !!!! have a response about that ??

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Dávid's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45793428/10560289) answer, this is the func created with completion:

```
func deleteAll(except types: Object.Type..., completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
    try? realm.write {
        realm.configuration.objectTypes?.filter{ type in
            types.contains{ $0 == type } == false
        }.forEach{ objectType in
            if let type = objectType as? Object.Type {
                realm.delete(realm.objects(type))
            }
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            completion()
        }
    }
}
```

or without completion (using async)

```
func deleteAll(except types: Object.Type...) async {
    try? realm.write {
        realm.configuration.objectTypes?.filter { type in
            types.contains { $0 == type } == false
        }.forEach { objectType in
            if let type = objectType as? Object.Type {
                realm.delete(realm.objects(type))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

implementation:

```
Task {
     await deleteAll(except: Cart.self)
     // code completion if needed
}
```