# How to delete all objects except one type?

Tags: swift, realm

I know I can do it easily with the following code:

```
realm.delete(realm.objects(Duck.self))
realm.delete(realm.objects(Frog.self))
//...
realm.delete(realm.objects(Cat.self))
```

But what is the best way to delete all objects except objects of one type?

Please note that I have I lot of types, and every time when I adding new type I should modify my `deleteAll` method.

Comment: This sounds kind of dangerous, what if you add a new type that shouldn't be deleted? Maybe it's better to modify that `deleteAll` method instead.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson, no it's safe because by default new type should be deleted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to Dávid's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45793428/1836420):

```
func deleteAll(except types: Object.Type...) {
    guard let realm = realm else { return }

    try? realm.write {
        realm.configuration.objectTypes?.filter{ type in types.contains{ $0 == type } == false}.forEach{ objectType in
            realm.delete(realm.objects(objectType.self))
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
deleteAll(except: Dog.self, Chicken.self)
```

Comment: In case that link breaks in the future could you add some of the core information from it in the answer, or maybe an example. it would make your answer much better

Comment: I dont have a mac right now to try it out but a other possible way is to let all your classes you want to delete inherit from a protocol. realm.delete(realm.object(ofType: type(of: YourProtocol)))

Comment: @Jonathan thanks, it works with some modification. I can edit your answer if you wish.

Comment: Yes update it! For the community :D

Comment: You shouldn't rely on a dynamically typed solution like this, especially cause this won't work if you have more than one bundles in your workspace, which will happen if you use several projects in a workspace. Especially since there's a type safe solution as the answer shows on the linked duplicate target.

Comment: Hi I used the solution but I got this error Could not cast value of type 'Element' (0x10522b338) to 'RealmSwift.Object' (0x106da4bc0 and my app crash

Comment: For Realm 10.0 and above use `if let type = objectType as? Object.Type { realm.delete(realm.objects(type)) }`